# Separability and Continuity

Tags: general-topology

I've always had a little bit of an issue with the general definition of continuous function for a topological space. We say a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for ever open set $U$ of $Y$, $f^{-1} (U)$ is open in $X$. I can understand this definition when it comes to metric spaces, but have always had trouble establishing intuition for general topological spaces.

Then I came across the concept of [separated sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separated_sets). Two sets are $A$ and $B$ are "separated by neighborhoods" if there are disjoint open sets U and V such that U contains A and V contains B. Using this definition it's not difficult to show that if two sets $A$ and $B$ are *inseparable* and f is continuous then the images $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ will also be inseparable.

This seems intuitive to me. A function separating something that was inseparable is "tearing something apart" and so discontinuous. It'd be nice if I could think of this as an "alternative" definition of continuous. But it's not clear to me whether the converse holds. That is, if a function satisfies this property does it mean that the function must be continuous? If not, are there any additional reasonable axioms I can add to make them equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

The converse need not hold.

Let $Y$ be an infinite set with the cofinite topology; then any two non-empty open sets in $Y$ have non-empty intersection. Thus, for any non-empty $A,B\subseteq Y$, $A$ and $B$ are inseparable. Let $X$ denote the same set with the indiscrete topology, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity map. Then $f$ is not continuous, but $f$ does preserve inseparability, since there are no separable pairs of non-empty sets in $Y$.